# Read in only the first n lines of a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I really just want the header of a csv file in R, not sure what the best way to do that is.

I thought something like

```
read.csv(readLines("file.csv", n=3))
```

might work, but of course the output of `readLines` isn't a valid connection.  I thought perhaps there's something clever to do with `stdin` here, but can't figure it out.

I'm looking for something better than just writing the readLines output to file and reading it back in, or manually implementing the header parsing that read.csv already does.  (Of course those approaches would work but they seem a bit crude; more generally I'm trying to understand how best to redirect text as a connection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `nrows=` argument to `read.table()` which is passed through.

Example:

```
R> dim(read.csv("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fortunes/fortunes/fortunes.csv", 
+      nrows=3, header=TRUE, sep=";"))
[1] 3 5
R>
```

(Pardon the `sep=";"` but I wanted to pick a file we'd both be likely to have ...)

Comment: My thanks! Not sure how I overlooked that. Still curious how to turn text into a connection without writing out to file, but I guess that's a separate issue.

Comment: @cboettig `?textConnection`?

Comment: @cboettig you could consider creating a question for this specific problem you had, and answering it. This will create a reference for other people with the same problem.